# How to sum timedeltas with resample or groupby in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame with TIME_IN and TIME_OUT columns (datetimes up to the second).  I want a new DF w/ the sum of the duration (TIME_OUT - TIME_IN) by date.  Each day runs from 5AM - 5AM, so I adjust for that as well.

This is part of a mini-project to teach myself Pandas, but my next application will be much more involved, so EFFICIENCY is key for me.

I've tried two approaches (resample and groupby), but both have the same issue: the timedelta DURATION column is not summing.

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime((df["TIME_IN"]                                    
             - dt.timedelta(hours=hrEnd)).dt.date)
df["DURATION"] = df["TIME_OUT"] - df["TIME_IN"]

dfGroupBy= df.groupby("DATE").sum()

df.setindex("DATE", inplace=True)
dfResample = df.resample("D").sum()
```

It seems Pandas does not sum timedelta64 type columns the way I attempted, so the returned DataFrame simply does not include the DURATION column. What is the most efficient way to do this?

EDIT: Here is a sample of the raw data right in df:
[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples?noredirect=1

Comment: @MichaelGardner Included a screenshot of the data within df above. This is what df looks like just before any of the code included above. Thanks!

Comment: pictures are not useful for us to create the DF & test it out. You have to paste the data as text or provide the csv file via some link.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `agg` function of grouped object to sum duration like below

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)

## Generate dummy data for testing
dt_range = pd.date_range("oct-12-2019", "oct-14-2019", freq="H")

arr = []
while len(arr)<10:
    i,j = np.random.choice(len(dt_range), 2)
    g = np.random.choice(4)
    if j>i:
        arr.append([g, dt_range[i], dt_range[j]])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["group", "time_in", "time_out"])


## Solution
df["duration"] = df["time_out"] - df["time_in"]
df.groupby(df["time_in"].dt.date).agg({"duration":np.sum})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code works as expected?

```
df['TIME_IN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_IN'])
df['TIME_OUT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_OUT'])
df['DATE'] = (df['TIME_IN'] - datetime.timedelta(hours=5)).dt.date
df["DURATION"] = df["TIME_OUT"] - df["TIME_IN"] 
df.groupby("DATE")['DURATION'].sum()
```

Input into groupby

```
    TIME_IN             TIME_OUT            DATE        DURATION
0   2019-05-06 11:46:51 2019-05-06 11:50:36 2019-05-06  00:03:45
1   2019-05-02 20:47:54 2019-05-02 20:52:22 2019-05-02  00:04:28
2   2019-05-05 07:39:02 2019-05-05 07:46:34 2019-05-05  00:07:32
3   2019-05-04 17:28:52 2019-05-04 17:32:57 2019-05-04  00:04:05
4   2019-05-05 14:08:26 2019-05-05 14:14:30 2019-05-05  00:06:04
```

Output after groupby

```
DATE
2019-05-02   00:04:28
2019-05-04   00:04:05
2019-05-05   00:13:36
2019-05-06   00:03:45
```

Seems to work as expected.